# HTML Aligning for Website

Tags: html, iframe, alignment

I want them to align beside each other and I can't use table formatting

```
<div align=left><a href="../data/home.htm" target="main_Frame"><img src="../data/banner.png" alt="Logo" width="20%" height="100%"></a></div>
<iframe name="main_Frame" height="100%" width="80%" src="../data/home.htm" frameborder="0" align="right"></iframe>
```

Comment: You need to learn CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div style="width:20%; float:left;"><a href="../data/home.htm" target="main_Frame"><img src="../data/banner.png" width="100%" alt="Logo"></a></div>
<div style="width:80%; float:right;"><iframe name="main_Frame" src="../data/home.htm" frameborder="0" width="100%"></iframe></div>
```

This should get them to align horizontally, provided they won't inherit some other styling attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just starting out you should try thinking of sites as blocks of divs before anything else,

```
<div style="position:relative; overflow:auto;">
    <div style = "width:20%; float:left;">
        <a href="../data/home.htm" target="main_Frame">
        <img src="../data/banner.png" alt="Logo"></a>
    </div>
    <div style = "width:80%; float:left;">
        <iframe name="main_Frame" src="../data/home.htm" frameborder="0" align="right"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would recommend learning some CSS, here is a good: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web